# file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, vesta

file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/{domain_name[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJE4u.jpg)}/public_html:/home/admin/tmp)

Please note-
1.using Ubuntu
2.Amazon AWS
3. Vesta Cp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your code as **text** rather than as a linked image.

Answer (score 0):

Path `/tmp` is outside your project directory, so access is denied because of `open_basedir` setting. You need to change `open_basedir` or use `temporaryPath` value within your project directory.